# HttpUrlConnection wont get a page

Tags: java, android, web

Trying to get page with

> http:www.thecinemas.aw/main/?date=2012-11-01

doesn't work anything. But

> http://www.thecinemas.aw/main/movies/details.html?id=1421

does work.

The only difference I can see is the use of a minus (`-`) in the first one.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first URL should start with `http://`, otherwise the protocol prefix is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "www.thecinemas.aw", "/main/?date=2012-11-01",null);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```